# Problem using include in Facelets

Tags: jsf, include, facelets

I have problems including a facelet template. I wanted to split some content up, so that I can reuse it somewhere else.

So I changed this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    template="/layout/template.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="head">
        <title>Title</title>
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="header">
        <h3>Header</h3>
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="content">
        <table><tr><td>table</td></tr></table>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

To this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    template="/layout/template.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="head">
        <title>Title</title>
    </ui:define>

    <ui:include src="/admin/admin_generic.xhtml"/>
</ui:composition>
```

And inside `admin-generic.xhtml` I wrapped the code in a ui:composition.

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

    <ui:define name="header">
        <h3>Header</h3>
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="content">
        <table><tr><td>table</td></tr></table>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

But nothing is shown. I just get a blank page, with no errors. Is it wrong using `ui:composition`? I have tried with `ui:component` but that didn't help either.

---

**Update**: According to my Facelets Essentials Guide, it says:

> The `ui:include` tag can be used to include another Facelets file into your
>   document. It simply includes whatever source file you specify. You can
>   include any Facelets file that has `ui:component` or `ui:composition` tags
>   **(which trim the content outside themselves)** or simply a fragment of
>   XHTML or XML.

Is that what is going on? Is the content outside of the include trimmed away? How can I just include the page, without the content outside being trimmed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [`<ui:define>`](https://facelets.dev.java.net/nonav/docs/dev/docbook.html#template-define) has to be placed in an `<ui:composition>` or `<ui:decorate>` **with** a `template` containing the appropriate `<ui:insert>` tags. You've moved it to an `<ui:composition>` *without* a `template`. No template means no content.

Technically, to achieve your requirement, you have to replace the `<ui:include>` by `<ui:insert>`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<ui:composition
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    template="template.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="head">
        <title>Title</title>
    </ui:define>

    <ui:insert />
</ui:composition>
```

And declare the above page (I assume it as `somepage.xhtml`) as `template` in `admin_generic.xhtml`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<ui:composition
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    template="somepage.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="header">
        <h1>Header</h1>
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="content">
        <table><tr><td>table</td></tr></table>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Note that you have to open `admin_generic.xhtml` in the browser instead. If your intent is to open `somepage.xhtml` in browser, then the `<ui:define>` really has to stay in `somepage.xhtml`. You can however replace the body of `<ui:define>` by a simple `<ui:include>`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<ui:composition 
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    template="template.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="head">
        <title>Title</title>
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="header">
        <h1>Header</h1>
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="content">
        <ui:include src="admin_generic.xhtml" />
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

It allows for `<ui:composition>`, so you don't necessarily need to put the `<table>` to root.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<ui:composition 
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

    <table><tr><td>table</td></tr></table>
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: You're welcome. In the future try to minimize irrelevant noise in the question so that others will answer it sooner :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by removing the `<ui:composition>` and the `<ui:define>` and just adding the namespace directly in the `<table>` like this:

```
<table class="adminform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:s="http://jboss.com/products/seam/taglib"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:a="http://richfaces.org/a4j">
```

So now my page looks like this:

```
<ui:define name="content">
    <ui:include src="/admin/admin_generic.xhtml" />
</ui:define>
```

Comment: You don't necessarily need to declare the table as root. An `ui:composition` would work as good. I think your misconception is caused by a lot of trial'n'error. The whole point is that the `ui:define` has to go in an `ui:composition` with a `template`.